# Angualrjs <select> ng-model adds strange string

Tags: html, angularjs

In my angular js application I have used  as follows

```
<select id='baseline' class="form-control" ng-model='vm.modal.baseline'>
   <option ng-repeat='base in vm.baseline' ng-value='base'>{{base}}</option>
</select>
```

Then in my controller

```
vm.baseline = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
vm.modal = {baseline: '3'};
```

but select is not defaulting to 3 instead it adds

```
<option value="? string:3 ?"></option>
```

What should I do to set the default value as 3? Thank you.

Comment: Are you want to 3 default selected ?

Comment: Yes, I want to set 3 as default.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your controller AS syntax, it is working correctly with $scope see the eg with your code.

https://jsfiddle.net/6r5Lnasb/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">    
    <select id='baseline' class="form-control" ng-model='modal.baseline'>
   <option ng-repeat='base in baseline' ng-value='base'>{{base}}</option>
</select>
</div>

function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.baseline = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
$scope.modal = {baseline: '3'};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because ng-model value is a string and option value is number.
  Change `vm.modal = {baseline: 3};` or convert `baseline` to array of strings `vm.baseline = ['1', '2', '3' ...];`

Comment: Ok, take a look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-pddaxh?file=home%2Fhome.controller.js

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing these two lines

```
vm.baseline = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
vm.modal = {baseline: '3'};
```

with below lines

```
vm = {
 baseline: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 modal:  {
  baseline: '3'
 }
}
```

As the variable `vm` is not defined/declared something like `var vm;` or `var vm = {};` or `var vm = null` assigning an array value or any value to a property of an undefined variable will throw an error hence it was not working.

if you have seen your browser console you might have got some similar looking error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'baseline' of undefined`

Comment: I set vm.modal = {}; at the top of everything.

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer if vm is not declared/defined vm.modal = {} will throw an error as vm is undefined and you are setting modal = {} on an undefined varible.

Comment: I set var vm = this;
        vm.modal = {}; at the top

Comment: Share some more context about your code. Try setting a breakpoint when assigning values to vm.baseline and watch the value of vm before and after assign